Need a shorter solution for this integration.
F(x) = integrate ((l + x)((l - x + x ^ 2)(l + x + x ^ 2) + x ^ 2))/(1 + 2x + 3x ^ 2 + 4x ^ 3 + 3x ^ 4 + 2x ^ 5 + x ^ 6) dx
So, the question is:
If $F(x) = \int \frac{(1 + x) \left( (1 - x + x^2)(1 + x + x^2) + x^2 \right)}{1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 3x^4 + 2x^5 + x^6} \, dx$ then find the Value of $[F(99)-F(3)]$.[Note: [K] denotes greatest integer function less than or equal to K.]
I tried solving the question by approaching $1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 3x^4 + 2x^5 + x^6 =(x + 1)^2 (x^2 + 1)^2$
\begin{align*}
F(x) &= \int \frac{(1 + x) \left( (1 - x + x^2)(1 + x + x^2) + x^2 \right)}{(x + 1)^2 (x^2 + 1)^2} \, dx \\[10pt]
F(x) &= \int \frac{(1 + x) \left( \left( x^2 + 1 \right)^2 - \left( x^2 \right) + x^2 \right)}{(x + 1)^2 (x^2 + 1)^2} \, dx \\[10pt]
F(x) &= \int \frac{(1 + x) \left( x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 - x^2 + x^2 \right)}{(x + 1)^2 (x^2 + 1)^2} \, dx \\[10pt]
F(x) &= \int \frac{(1 + x)(x^4 + 2x^2 + 1)}{(x + 1)^2 (x^2 + 1)^2} \, dx \\[10pt]
F(x) &= \int \frac{(1 + x)(x^2 + 1)^2}{(x + 1)^2 (x^2 + 1)^2} \, dx \\[10pt]
F(x) &= \int \frac{1}{(x + 1)} \, dx \\[10pt]
F(x) &= \ln(x+1) \\[10pt]
\end{align*}
Putting $F(99)$ and $F(3)$:
\begin{align*}
&F(99) - F(3) = \ln(100) - \ln(4) \\[10pt]
&F(99) - F(3) = \ln(\frac{100}{4}) \\[10pt]
&F(99) - F(3) = \ln(25) \\[10pt]
&F(99) - F(3) = 2 \cdot \ln(5) \\[10pt]
&F(99) - F(3) = 2  \times 1.6094 \\[10pt]
&F(99) - F(3) = 3.218 \\[10pt]
\end{align*}
So, the greatest integer function
\begin{align*}
&[F(99) - F(3)]= 3
\end{align*}
Is there any shorter way to Solve?

This seems to be the fastest way! This question appears to be designed to be solved this way.
